# WP7 Adding data to infinite listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm trying to implement an "infinite" listbox that will load new data each time the end of listbox is reached. Issue occurs when I try to deserialize the next set of search results. I'm getting a `Operation not supported on read-only collection`.

Here are my classes.

```
public class Search
{
    //public Spellcheck spellcheck { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ResultSearch> results = new ObservableCollection<ResultSearch>();

    public IEnumerator<ResultSearch> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class ResultSearch
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string mixName { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public object isrc { get; set; }
    public string releaseDate { get; set; }
    public string publishDate { get; set; }
    public string sampleUrl { get; set; }
    public string rtmpStreamUrl { get; set; }
    public bool exclusive { get; set; }
    public Price price { get; set; }
    //public AudioFormatFee audioFormatFee { get; set; }
    public string currentStatus { get; set; }
    public string length { get; set; }
    public int bpm { get; set; }
    public Key key { get; set; }
    public string saleType { get; set; }
    public List<SearchArtist> artists { get; set; }
    public List<SearchGenre> genres { get; set; }
    public List<object> subGenres { get; set; }
    public List<SearchChart> charts { get; set; }
    public SearchRelease release { get; set; }
    public SearchLabel label { get; set; }
    public SearchImages images { get; set; }
    //public DynamicImages dynamicImages { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class SearchArtist
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class SearchGenre
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class SearchChart
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class SearchRelease
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class SearchLabel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class SearchImages
{
    //public Small small { get; set; }
    //public SearchMedium medium { get; set; }
    public SearchLarge large { get; set; }
    //public SearchBanner banner { get; set; }
    //public Waveform waveform { get; set; }
}

public class SearchLarge
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string secureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing the new data

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string searchTxt = String.Empty;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("searchTxt", out searchTxt))
        {
            searchTxtBox.Text = searchTxt;
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(searchTxt);
            LaunchWebClient(searchTxt);
        }
    }

    private void LaunchWebClient(string searchTxt)
    {
        // WebClient jsonSearch
        WebClient jsonSearch = new GzipWebClient();
        Uri apiSearch = new Uri("http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search?query=" + searchTxt);
        jsonSearch.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(jsonSearch_GetDataCompleted);
        jsonSearch.DownloadStringAsync(apiSearch);
    }

    // When end of listbox is reached
    private void LaunchWebClientNextpage(int page)
    {
        int pageLimit = page;
        if (pageLimit <= 5)
        {
            // WebClient jsonSearch
            WebClient jsonSearch = new GzipWebClient();
            Uri apiSearch = new Uri("http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/search?query=" + searchTxtBox.Text + "&page=" + page);
            jsonSearch.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(jsonSearchNextPage_GetDataCompleted);
            jsonSearch.DownloadStringAsync(apiSearch);
        }
        else
        {
            SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, false);
            //SystemTray.SetOpacity(this, 0.0);
            prog.IsVisible = false;
            prog.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
    }

    // Deserialize search json data
    public void jsonSearch_GetDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Search searchData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(e.Result);

        if (searchData.results.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your search didn't return any results");
        }
        else
        {
            this.listSearch.ItemsSource = searchData.results;
        }
    }

    // Deserialize search next page json data
    public void jsonSearchNextPage_GetDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Search searchDataPage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(e.Result);

        //listSearch.Items.Add(searchDataPage.results);
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

Here is my xaml as well

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">            
        <ListBox x:Name="listSearch" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding images.medium.url}" Tap="searchSelectedImageHandler" Margin="10" Width="60" Height="60" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Tap="searchSelectedHandler" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding type}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has a `class Search` with an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<ResultSearch> results = new ObservableCollection<ResultSearch>();
```

However, the deserialization is attempting to add to a `listSearch`:

```
listSearch.Items.Add(searchDataPage.results);
```

I suspect, the items should be added to the `results` collection instead of the `listSearch` control.

**Edit in response to comments**:

The quickest (not the most ideal) thing to do here is to create an ObservableCollection in your code-behind and then set the ItemsSource of the ListBox to the ObservableCollection and modify the json methods:

```
// code behind for your xaml
public partial class MyCodeBehind
{
  public ObservableCollection<Search> Searches;

  public MyCodeBehind()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    Searches = new ObservableCollection<Search>();
    // bind the collection to the ListBox
    this.listSearch.ItemsSource = Searches;
  }

  // Deserialize search json data
  public void jsonSearch_GetDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    Search searchData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(e.Result);

    if (searchData.results.Count == 0)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("your search didn't return any results");
    }
    else
    {
      // add the results to the existing Searches collection
      foreach (Search search in searchData.results)
      {
        Searches.Add(search);
      }
    }
  }

  // Deserialize search next page json data
  public void jsonSearchNextPage_GetDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    Search searchDataPage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search>(e.Result);

    // add the results to the existing Searches collection
    foreach (Search search in searchDataPage)
    {
      Searches.Add(search);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I having a hard time figuring this out. Could you provide an example?

Comment: See the edit. If that doesn't work, you'll need to add the additional code that binds the collection to the listbox.

Comment: I'm getting a `results does not exist in the current context` error. also see my update for my xaml

Comment: Where is the `jsonSearchNextPage_GetDataCompleted` method (which class)? And where are you setting the `DataContext` to the ListBox? I think you may need to post the code behind of your XAML.

Comment: The data get set in the initial webclient `this.listSearch.ItemsSource = searchData.results`(see additional code above). I can do this on the `NextPage` webclient, but it only replaces the data.